# Shopify fulfillment

Tags: json

The online shopify docs for fulfillment show this example:

```
POST /admin/orders/#{id}/fulfillments.json  

{  
  "fulfillment": {  
    "tracking_number": null,  
    "line_items": [  
      {  
       "id": 466157049  
      }  
     ]  
  }  
}
```

The docs also say that not specifying an item id will cause all items to fulfill.

My postdata to that api endpoint reads:

```
{"fulfillment":{"tracking_number":null}}
```

This comes back:

```
{"errors":{"fulfillment":"can't be blank"}}
```

I have tried this:

```
{"fulfillment":{"tracking_number":null,"line_items":[{"id":300668234}]}}
```

which is a valid item id for my order.  The same message comes back.

Ideas?

Comment: try using headers: accept application/json

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting your Content-Type to `application/json`?

Trying sending the same request using cURL

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @fulfillment.json https://API_KEY:API_TOKEN@SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/orders/ORDER_ID/fulfillments.json`

If that works, it means you aren't sending your request correctly.

Comment: A careful compare of my request after successfully making the above curl request revealed the issue. Thank you.  For future reference, is it possible to get curl to disgorge the header that it creates prior to the call?

Comment: Just use curl in verbose mode (-v)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fulfillment": {"tracking_number": "123456789","notify_customer": true}}' https://API_KEY:TOKEN@SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/orders/ORDER_ID/fulfillments.json
```

This is the working example of updating tracking number for an order. It took me a minute to realize that the ORDER_ID is the long form shopify order id. It should be about 9 to 10 digits.